# Symfony Monolog rewrites the same file

Tags: symfony, monolog

I have my service with Monolog:

```
cmd_local.logger:
        class:     Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
        arguments: [app]
        calls:
            - [pushHandler, [@cmd_local.logger_handler]]

    cmd_local.logger_handler:
        class:     Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
        arguments: [%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.cmd.local.log, 200]
```

What I need now is to rewrite (or delete and write) the same file when this file is older than *x* days.

I read about log rotation, but that is not what I need. I don't need to save this file with another name and start rewriting it. I just want to rewrite this file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom Handler for custom loggers (one day = one log file).

```
class FilenameContainsDateStreamHandler extends StreamHandler
{

public function __construct(
    $stream,
    $level = Logger::DEBUG,
    $bubble = true,
    $filePermission = null,
    $useLocking = false
) {
    $stream = str_replace(
        '.log', '-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log', $stream
    );

    parent::__construct(
        $stream,
        $level,
        $bubble,
        $filePermission,
        $useLocking
    );
}
}
```

and regiterate new loggers

```
your.logger:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [your_tag]
    calls:
        - [pushHandler, [@your.monolog.handler]]
your.monolog.handler:
    class: AppBundle\Monolog\Handler\FilenameContainsDateStreamHandler
    arguments: [%kernel.logs_dir%/your.log]
```

$this->get('your.logger')->info();

and one more

```
crm.logger:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [crm_tag]
    calls:
        - [pushHandler, [@crm.monolog.handler]]
crm.monolog.handler:
    class: AppBundle\Monolog\Handler\FilenameContainsDateStreamHandler
    arguments: [%kernel.logs_dir%/crm.log]
```

$this->get('crm.logger')->info();